# removing index.php causes css to break

Tags: htaccess, css

I am trying to use the recommended htaccess file to remove the index.php.

but when I clear the Name of your site's index page in admin prefs the css will not load but everything else will on the templates.

my css:  `<link href="{stylesheet=global_embeds/site_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />`

viewing source it appears fine: `<link href="http://domain.com/?css=global_embeds/site_css.v.1379946470" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

CSS is a css template in EE

Comment: Please provide your .htaccess instead of referring to "recommended". Also confirm your CSS file - is it a template or physical file on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(css=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(ACT=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/%1 [L]
```

Before your main index rewrite.

Also if it's a physical file, ensure you have this in your htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Before the index rewrite rule.

So your htaccess may look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(css=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/%1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|admin|themes|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(ACT=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I'm guessing your CSS is a template in "global_embeds" template group...? If so, keep it simple and change your html code as follows:

```
<link href="/global_embeds/site_css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

Comment: thanks all I had to do is change: <link href="/global_embeds/site_css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

which is weird because the original method has word previously